# SQL2 query for accessing tags from assets

Tags: aem, jcr-sql2

I want to know what is the SQL2 query for accessing child nodes of a parent node for full text search.

I have an image saved into assets named `men-watches.png`. I have created a tag named `watches` and assigned this tag to asset mentioned above.

I have done the same with other images too. Please help me with the SQL2 full text search query as I want to search this asset.

I tried

```
select * from [dam:Asset] as d where contains (d.[jcr:content/metadata/cq:tags] = ‘watches’)
```

But I am asked to write a full text search query in SQL2 using `IN clause` for tags ‘watches’ and writing it for not only checking tags, but also for checking for title or description too.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood it correctly, but this example would search if one of provided tags are on some images.

```
SELECT * FROM [dam:Asset] AS asset WHERE (asset.[jcr:content/metadata/cq:tags] IN ('watches','something else')) AND ISDESCENDANTNODE(asset,'/content/dam')
```